# how to lessen the time load in selecting data in database

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to find out if there is another way to lessen the time load when getting the data in database of my code:

```
SELECT cust.CUSTOMERNAME, cust.STDTERMS, (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) 
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear,'-',StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear,'-',EndDate) AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME
        ) AS Amount, intYear AS intYear,
        (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) 
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear1,'-',StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear1,'-',EndDate) AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType  AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME
        ) AS Amount2, intYear1 AS intYear2,
        (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) 
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear2,'-',StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear2,'-',EndDate) AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType  AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME
        ) AS Amount3, intYear2 AS intYear3,
        (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) 
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear3,'-',StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear3,'-',EndDate) AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType  AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME
        ) AS Amount4, intYear3 AS intYear4,
        (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) 
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear4,'-',StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear4,'-',EndDate) AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType  AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME
        ) AS Amount5, intYear4 AS intYear5

        FROM 000_customer cust WHERE cust.CUSTOMERNAME = thecustomer;
```

in this code it will select all the total amount of each selected 5 years 
that will look like this, just ignore the values.
[image]

can anyone out there have a suggestion to make this code become timeless to load?
when getting data from the database?
i tried inner join but the result when getting the data from database is not correct. and i cant use the variable that i am using in where clause:

```
from 000_customer cust where cust.customername = '%'
```

if i use what is the current customername value in the select query inside of inner joined table. i will get an error stating cust.customername is unknown column.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        WHERE act.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2017','-','01-01') AND CONCAT('2017','-','12-30') AND act.CUSTOMER = cust.customername
```

so the the query can determine what cust.customername value have it now. because i actually want to display the total amount of each customer in each 5 years. not the total years. just each year. like the example above.

suggestion's is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

UPDATED CODE:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERNAME, c.STDTERMS,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2017', '-', '01-01') AND CONCAT('2017', '-', '12-30')
        THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Amount1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2016', '-', '01-01') AND CONCAT('2016', '-', '12-30')
        THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Amount2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2015', '-', '01-01') AND CONCAT('2015', '-', '12-30')
        THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Amount3,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2014', '-', '01-01') AND CONCAT('2014', '-', '12-30')
        THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Amount4,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT('2013', '-', '01-01') AND CONCAT('2013', '-', '12-30')
        THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Amount5
        FROM 000_customer c JOIN
        100_actual_transaction a
        ON a.CUSTOMER = c.CUSTOMERNAME AND 
        a.SALESTYPE LIKE '%'
        WHERE c.CUSTOMERNAME LIKE '%'
        GROUP BY c.CUSTOMERNAME, c.STDTERMS;
```

I've just put a value so it clarify my  main logic. thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  I'm not sure exactly what your logic is, but something like this:

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERNAME, c.STDTERMS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.ATDATE BETWEEN CONCAT(intYear, '-', StartDate) AND CONCAT(intYear, '-', EndDate)
                THEN COALESCE(a.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - COALESCE(a.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)
                ELSE 0
           END) as Amount
FROM 000_customer c JOIN
     100_actual_transaction a
     ON a.CUSTOMER = c.CUSTOMERNAME AND
        a.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType
WHERE c.CUSTOMERNAME = thecustomer
GROUP BY c.CUSTOMERNAME, c.STDTERMS;
```

I can't really tell what is a column and what is a variable.  I'm pretty sure this is the logic you are looking for.  You need to repeat the `SUM(CASE)` for each calculated column you want in the output.

Comment: wow!... i am really thankful to you pal.. you are a genius. you really saved me. but i would just like to ask what is the meaning of the COALESCE? hehehe.. because i really don't know it.. you know what? i already know how to use the inner join but the SUM(CASE) i don't know how to use it. but know you clarify it for me.

Comment: @AlvinIlmo . . . `COALESCE()` is the ANSI standard function that is a bit more powerful than `IFNULL()`.

Comment: thank you very much once again hope my problem can solve other people that have the same or similar to my problem.